# Hamiltonian function, stationary points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is Hamiltonian function $H(x,y) = (x - y)^2 + 2sin(x+y)$. I shall show that $(-\pi, -\pi), (\pi, \pi)$ are stationary points of Hamiltionian system and at the same time stationary points of $H$.

My attempt: I make Hamiltonian system:
$x' = H_y = -2(x-y) + 2cos(x+y)$
$$ y' = H_x = -(2(x-y) + 2cos(x+y)$$

If I insert $(-\pi, -\pi), (\pi, \pi)$ into Hamiltionian system I get $x' = 0$ and $y' = 0$. So the points are stationary points of Hamiltonian system.

Now, I am wondering, how do we show wheter the points are stationary points of $H$. It seems to me that if the points are stationary of Hamiltionian system, then they should also be s.p. of $H$.

The next question that arises to me is, how do we determine the properties of stationary points. I would be thankful is someoene would advice me, which method to apply. I will use the Jacobian matrix in order to get eigenvalues of stationary points. I hope that I am on the right track.